# Calculating daily lag

Tags: ruby

Is there a nicer way to calculate lag (value - previous value) in ruby? This is what I came up with. If the lag is greater than 0 I return `1`, if it is less I return `-1`

(my code below does not work. Using ruby 2.3.5)

```
def lagChange(arr,k=1)
  prev=nil
  ret=[]
  arr.each{|x|
    if(x.to_i>-9999)
      ret<<if(x-prev>0){1}else{-1}end
    else
      ret<<"NA"
    end
    prev=x.to_i
  }
  return ret
end

lagChange([1,2,3,5]) #NA 1 1 -1
```

Comment: Did you consider returning `[1,1,-1]` rather than `["#NA",1,1,-1]`? btw, Ruby does not charge extra for spaces. One Ruby convention is to use "snake case" for names of variables and methods (`lag_change` rather than `lagChange`). You don't have to follow that convention, but 99% of Rubiests do. Also, `return ret` is the same as `ret`. `return` is normally not used when it is not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the spaceship operator might come in handy here:

```
def lagChange(arr)
  arr.map.with_index do |x, idx|
    idx == 0 ? "NA" : x <=> arr[idx - 1]
  end
end

lagChange([1,2,2,1])
 => ["NA", 1, 0, -1]
```

Note that this also returns 0 if they are equal(no lag).

Answer (score 5):

`if(x-prev>0){1}else{-1}end` is not valid Ruby.

```
def lagChange(arr,k=1)
  prev = nil
  ret = []
  arr.each{|x|
    if prev == nil
      ret << "NA"
    elsif(x.to_i>-9999)
      ret << (x-prev > 0 ? 1 : -1)
    end
    prev=x.to_i
  }
  return ret
end

lagChange([1,2,3,1])
=> ["NA", 1, 1, -1]
```

A shorter version could be

```
def lag_change(arr)
  arr.each_cons(2).map {|x,y| y-x > 0 ? 1 : -1}.unshift('NA')
end

> lag_change([1,2,3,1])
=> ["NA", 1, 1, -1]
```